# Check number of connections to MySQL in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-connection

Is it possible to check the number of connections to a **mysql** server in **codeigniter**?

I Have two CI Applications which I access each other's database. However, I get the following error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 347

When I opened my logs I saw a warning which said `Too Many Connections`.

So I want to debug why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

There are mysql query to see opened connection. You may run following query to see all corresponding variables and their value

In CI3

```
$ww = $this->db->query('show status like "%conn%"');
$t = $ww->result_array();
var_dump($t);
```

here `Threads_connected` variable is number of connection currently opened in MySQL. You may extract it as

```
echo $t['13']['Value'];
```